# Serialize C# Dictionary as JSON object using WCF with HTTP

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I'm new to WCF services with HTTP Routing, but my new project uses WCF. The services return objects marked with with [`[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836683/when-to-use-datacontract-and-datamember-attributes) returned as part of services marked with [`[ServiceContract]`  and `[OperationContract]` attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-data-contracts)

I want to return a class with a `Dictionary<string, string>` like this:

```
var myObject = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "aKey", "aValue" } };
```

I want it to JSON serialize like this:

```
{
  "aKey": "aValue"
}
```

But it serializes like this:

```
[{
  "Key": "aKey",
  "Value": "aValue"
}]
```

How can I do that with WCF + HTTP?

- I can see [this question/answer showing how to change JsonSerializeSettings with MVC / ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58392039/how-to-set-json-serializer-settings-in-asp-net-core-3/58392418#58392418), but WCF is different, right?

I found many helpful answers, but they don't show me how to do it in the WCF/HTTP context so REST responses are automatically JSON serialized

- I see [this question/answer uses `DataContractJsonSerializerSettings`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20563358/1175496), specifically with `UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true`

  - but this example writes to a `MemoryStream`; where would I specify that in a WCF project sot he REST response is returned? in the Web.config? In Global.asax.cs?
- This [question/answer uses a custom `[JsonConverter]` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547550/c-sharp-json-custom-serialization)

  - Let me try that; I assume I can try that using the attribute directly on my property
- There's also [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893614/how-to-serialize-a-dictionary-as-part-of-its-parent-object-using-json-net) which uses [the `[JsonExtensionData]` attribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonExtensionDataAttribute.htm)

  - I can also try that; I assume I can try that using the attribute directly on my property
- [What does the `[JsonDictionary]` attribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonDictionaryAttribute.htm) do? It seems like it might be helpful here
- And maybe [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31532750/1175496) is exactly what I need...
- (Also for reference just linking [this question on WCF services with HTTP routing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3056730/1175496) more generally, because I'm new to WCF...)
- And [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45139813/wcf-datacontract-mapping-json-object-to-c-sharp-dictionary) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748305/wcf-dictionarystring-object-serialization) questions

**EDIT**

- Here is [a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30494436/1175496)
- And see discussions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6792899/1175496)
- I have similar issues when I try to specify how to [deserialize a C# Date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635599/specifying-a-custom-datetime-format-when-serializing-with-json-net)

  - There may be some hope in the [WCF Message Formatters post here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/carlosfigueira/wcf-extensibility-message-formatters)

Comment: Do [Make ASP.NET WCF convert dictionary to JSON, omitting "Key" & "Value" tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7590088) or [How to return a Dictionary of custom type values as a regular JSON object from a WCF REST method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35490329/3744182) answer your question?

Comment: Yes they give me workarounds if I understand, let me try those... maybe I can mark my question as duplicate. Your [first link shows how I can do it by creating a custom class that extends `ISerializable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590088/make-asp-net-wcf-convert-dictionary-to-json-omitting-key-value-tags) and the [second link shows how I can do it by writing to the response manually using `WebOperationContext.Current.CreateTextResponse`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35512633/1175496)

Comment: Thanks @dbc [your second suggestion worked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77484178/1175496). I'm not sure why the first suggestion didn't work (I kinda like the first suggestion...) maybe my project is not configured to use `ISerializable` in the way it would need for hte first suggestion. Thanks, I'm OK to close this question as duplicate or something, or if you answer I'll give you credit! Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried an approach from @dbc's first suggestion, by [creating my own class which extends `ISerializable`. See my modified class below.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590088/make-asp-net-wcf-convert-dictionary-to-json-omitting-key-value-tags). Right now that doesn't work for  me, the `GetObjectData` method is never called, at least my debug breakpoint doesn't hit it. That suggests maybe my project is not using a default serializer (?)

```
[Serializable]
public class SerializableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : ISerializable, IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IEnumerable
{
    //https://stackoverflow.com/a/7590189/1175496
    private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> _Dictionary;
    public SerializableDictionary(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
    {
        _Dictionary = dictionary;
    }
    public SerializableDictionary() : this(new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>()) { }

    public SerializableDictionary(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : this(new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>()) {
    /* no deserializing */
    //https://stackoverflow.com/a/47187399/1175496
    }


    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get { return _Dictionary[key]; }
        set { _Dictionary[key] = value; }
    }

    public ICollection<TKey> Keys => this._Dictionary.Keys;

    public ICollection<TValue> Values => this._Dictionary.Values;

    public int Count => this._Dictionary.Count;

    public bool IsReadOnly => true;

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        _Dictionary.Add(key, value);
    }

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _Dictionary.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        foreach (TKey key in _Dictionary.Keys)
            info.AddValue(key.ToString(), _Dictionary[key]);
    }

    public bool Remove(TKey key)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
    {
        return this._Dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this._Dictionary.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Instead I tried the approach from @dbc's second suggestion, and **it worked**. It relies on [returning a  `System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message` manually, as shown below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35512633/1175496) so I don't love it.

I'd prefer to use `DataContractJsonSerializerSettings.UseSimpleDictionaryFormat` [as @dbc suggests, but it's not exposed, as @dbc says!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35490329/how-to-return-a-dictionary-of-custom-type-values-as-a-regular-json-object-from-a#comment58673937_35490329)).
So for now, this may be the best way. If there are no other suggestions, eventually I'll close the question as duplicate or something... **Thanks, @dbc!**

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet( UriTemplate = "/getResponse", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public Message GetResponse()
    {

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "key", "value" } });
        return WebOperationContext.Current.CreateTextResponse(json, "application/json; charset=utf-8", Encoding.UTF8);

    }
```